# What user does Subversiion use?

Tags: svn, hook

I'm trying to create an SVN hook script. Unfortunately this is failing with an exit code 255. I suspect the problem may be related to permissions as my script creates a file in the Hooks folder.

What user does SVN use when it commits to the repo? What user is SVN using when it executes its hooks?

Answer (score 2):

Your hook script executes as the user under which your server process executes.

- If you serve with HTTP, then it's the user Apache runs under.
- If you serve with svnserve, then it's the user svnserve runs under
- If you use `svn+ssh`, it's the committing user (in most cases)
- If you use `file:///`, it's the committing user

Comment: We use HTTP but running IIS so I assume it's running under the IIS context.

Comment: Subversion cannot be served natively by IIS AFAIK. If you're really interacting with IIS directly from the client, IIS is then proxying that activity to something else, which could be running as a different user.

Comment: We use VisualSVN under IIS to browse to our repos.

Comment: VisualSVN Server bundles Apache. It does not hook into or use IIS.

Comment: VisualSVN and its associated repositories are installed on a Windows 2008 Server. I need to figure out which user SVN is using so I can elevate their privileges to be able to have write access to the hooks folder. So far I can't figure out what user that is.

Comment: I can't see Apache running as a service or see any Apache user in Computer Management.

Comment: It may be listed as `httpd` or `VisualSVN Server`, not Apache. Easy test: shut down IIS on the box. Can you still access your repositories?

Comment: Found it. There's a user called VisualSVN Server that runs under the NETWORK SERVICE context.